# _wfreopen works on c:/path/file.txt but not with c:\path\file.txt?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, string

```
TCHAR finalpath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,finalpath);
TCHAR filename[] = TEXT("\\lista.txt");
wcscat(finalpath,filename);
wprintf(L"List will be saved to %s", finalpath);
```

So this basically confirms me that finalpath is indeed c:\somepath\lista.txt

but `_wfreopen(TEXT(finalpath),TEXT("w"),stdout);`

If i just change it to

```
_wfreopen(TEXT("c:/somepath/lista.txt"),TEXT("w"),stdout);
```

everything then works fine, why and how can i make it accept my finalpath arg?

Thanks

Comment: I think the probles is that the path returned by `GetCurrentDirectory()` is not terminated by a backslash. You need an extra `wcscat()` call to add a backslash before adding the `filename` string.

Comment: @thkala: There is a leading backslash in `filename`.  Plus this problem would show up in the `wprintf` output.

Comment: BTW: If you want the code to work under both ANSI and Unicode, it needs to be `_tcscat`, `_tprintf` and `_tfreopen`.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling for POSIX instead of Win32?

Comment: @Lambert: your answer would make a very good comment, and one I'd agree with, even though I felt it wasn't THE solution.

Comment: no, i am compiling for win32, btw removing TEXT from finalpath arg didnt solve problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the TEXT macro with variables.  I'm surprised that `_wfreopen(TEXT(finalpath),TEXT("w"),stdout);` even compiles.

Try `_wfreopen(finalpath,TEXT("w"),stdout);`

Comment: This. If finalpath is of type TCHAR[] then you don't need to modify it. TEXT is only for literals.

Comment: finalpath has already the correct type. the TEXT macro has no effect, albeit wrong used. I think your answer doesn't help.

Comment: @user47249: On what basis do you think it has no effect?  The compiler will still do the substitution.  For reference, the definition is `#define __TEXT(quote) L##quote`, so it actually becomes a reference to a variable named `Lfinalpath`... which either won't compile or accidentally pulls in a variable with that name from elsewhere.

Comment: ...followed by `#define TEXT(quote) __TEXT(quote)`

Comment: sorry for wrong reply above, i should post it here, _wfreopen(finalpath,TEXT("w"),stdout); didnt fix anything

Comment: Hmmm... put a breakpoint in the debugger and make sure that there aren't any non-printable characters hidden in your variables?

Comment: Tried, all seems good. I am using .dll as plugin file for autoit(script language) perhaps this is where problem is coming from. I assume it starts with GetCurrentDirectory() as that is the dir of autoit script which is calling the dll file, no idea what to do and how to debug this. ]

Comment: If `TEXT(quote)` is evaluated as just `quote`, then you aren't compiling in Unicode mode, and the explicit references to `_w...` functions are wrong. If you are using `TCHAR` and `TEXT()` then you must universally use `_tcs...` functions from `tchar.h`. Otherwise, you have the appearance of compatibility with both ANSI and UNICODE, but if the compilation ever changes to the other mode you will be in pain. Regardless, only apply `TEXT()` or `_T()` to actual string literals, never to a variable.

Comment: @RBerteig: I agree, and I left a comment to that effect above on the question about an hour ago.  In my answer I was just trying to solve the immediate problem.

Comment: It seems that my problem is something totally different, i tested this in dummy project and all works ok. The problem is not with my code but something else. The function that uses global dll parameter(destination file path) and topens it, belongs to another thread and that is why it didn't recognize the finalpath variable. I believe this is totally another subject so since Ben Voigt waws right and gave me best info i will take his answer as accepted, thanks all who helped, this or that way.

Comment: @Ben, I see I didn't point my comment at anyone specific. It wasn't really aimed at your answer. I was really reacting to @Marko29's claim that it compiled, which implies the macro was defined for ANSI but he is using UNICODE functions. I strongly suspect the real problems run deeper than this, especially given Marko29's new comment about a DLL not recognizing a variable.....

Comment: Again, this was not a problem with code but interprocess communication issue, i was sending a pointer to another process.thread, thats why it turned empty in another thread(couldnt see it due to process boundaries), this is solved by wm_copydata message though