# How would you use a variable in place of volume in mciSendString? C++

Tags: c++, audio, volume, mcisendstring

So I am making a basic 2D fighting game using C++. And for sound/audio effects I am using *mciSendString()*

```
            mciSendString(TEXT("setaudio sounds\\character_select.mp3 volume to 500"), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

This above code works fine. It sets the volume of the sound to 500; however, I do not want to hard-code the volume value. I want it to progressively get smaller without having to copy and paste the same line over and over with just a smaller integer value for volume.

```
            mciSendString(TEXT("setaudio sounds\\character_select.mp3 volume to " + volume ), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I want to do something like this. Where instead of having a hard-coded 500 I could have a variable with any integer value in it. However when I run it I get no errors and the audio continues playing like it normally would at 1000 instead of 500.

What would I do to fix this?

Comment: See here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589512/wfreopen-works-on-c-path-file-txt-but-not-with-c-path-file-txt/4589545#4589545

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot use the `TEXT()` macro with variables. It's only meant to be used with character array literals like `"Hello"` and places an `L` before the literal, depending on which option (multibyte wide strings or UTF8) is used to compile the code.

For the latter option you can use a `std::string` variable to compose your command:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
int volume = 300;
oss << "setaudio sounds\\character_select.mp3 volume to " << volume;
std::string cmd = oss.str();

mciSendString(cmd.c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

For the other option, you need to use `std::wstring`, `std::wostringstream` accordingly.

Comment: With the code you provided I'm getting the error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" at cmd.c_str()

Comment: @CurtisPhillips Determine what your compiler environment (multibyte wide strings or UTF8) is setup actually.

Comment: You can distable UTF8 in your application by going to project Properities -> General -> Character Set  and setting it to "Not Set".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with mcisendstring since you are using c++ I recommend you do as I did previously to work this issue out

make a function called mcicommand as follow:

```
    #include <string>
    string mcicommand(string volume){
    
        string command = "setaudio song volume to ";
        
        int found = command.find_last_of(" ");
        command = command.substr(0, found) + " " + volume;
        
        return command;
}
```

now whenever you want to call upon this function with mcisendstring do this

```
string volume;
cin >> volume;
vol_command = mcicommand(volume)
mcisendstring(vol_command.c_str , NULL, 0, NULL);
```